# Catching an exception in clone_saved_path()

Tags: python, sqlite, command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out how to get the exception to show for this function

```
clone_saved_path():

def clone_saved_path():

            except OSError as e:
                # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
                print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
                print("got here. [4]")
            except:
                print("Another error occurred in clone_saved_path() ")
                print("got here. [5]")
```

When I run my code, it hits the last `except` block and outputs:

```
print("Another error occurred in clone_saved_path() ")
```

I know this may sound basic, but I need to figure out how to show the *actual* exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info
"This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is currently being handled."

So you could do something like the below (suggested here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
import sys
# ...
        except:
            print("Another error occurred in clone_saved_path() ")
            print(sys.exc_info()[0]) # type of exception
            raise
```